# Does EF 4 Code First's ContextBuilder Dispose its SqlConnection?

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

Looking at Code First in ADO.Net EF 4 CTP 3 and wondered how the `SqlConnection` in [their walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610233056/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/22/feature-ctp-walkthrough-code-only-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) is disposed.  Is that the responsibility of ContextBuilder?  Is it missing from the example?

```
  var connection = new SqlConnection(DB_CONN);
  var builder = new ContextBuilder<BloggingModel>();
  var connection = new SqlConnection(DB_CONN);

  using (var ctx = builder.Create(connection))
  {
      //... 
  }
```

Comment: This code isn't quite what's on the link, but I presume that's a cut and paste error.

Comment: @Craig: Just abbreviated for clarity... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that I can add an event handler to ObjectContext.Disposing and resolve this.

In CTP 3 at least, Connection is *not* disposed when the ObjectContext is disposed.

Since I'm subclassing ObjectContext already, I implemented IDisposable in my subclass and call Connection.Dispose() from there.

Answer (score 0):

[`Close` and `Dispose` in `SqlConnection` are functionally equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close(v=VS.100).aspx). Therefore, as long as the connection is closed -- and I think you'll find that it is, but don't take my word for it -- the sample code works.

But since you asked, you should probably dispose of it anyway. It will do no harm, and will stop others from asking the same question.

Comment: I know that disposing the connection will also close it, but the sample code disposes ctx, not connection.  It's unknown (to me) whether the contract for ContextBuilder ensures that it will dispose (and therefore close) the connection it's given.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Because the ContextBuilder closes the connection, the connection does not need to be disposed.

Comment: ContextBuilder did not close the connection in my test (see my separate answer).